# pass bool variable by reference in function argument

Tags: c, pointers, tree, boolean, pass-by-reference

I am trying to include a boolean flag in the below function argument to see whether a value already exists in the current tree structure of values.

```
VLTreeNode *addNewNode(AVLTreeNode *currentNode, int k, int v, bool *ifExist)
{
    if (currentNode == NULL)
    {
        return newAVLTreeNode(k, v);
    }
    if (k == currentNode->key && v == currentNode->value)
    {
        *ifExist = true;
        return currentNode;
    }
    else if ((k == currentNode->key && v < currentNode->value) || k < currentNode->key)
    {
        currentNode->left = addNewNode(currentNode->left, k, v, &ifExist);
        currentNode->left->parent = currentNode;
    }
    else if ((k == currentNode->key && v > currentNode->value) || k > currentNode->key)
    {
        currentNode->right = addNewNode(currentNode->right, k, v, &ifExist);
        currentNode->right->parent = currentNode;
    }
}
```

The call of this function would be like the following:

```
    bool ifExist = false;
    Tree->root = addNewNode(Tree->root, k, v, &ifExist);
    
    if (ifExist)
    {
        T->size++;
    }
```

and it does not work... could someone give me some hints what goes wrong in the code. Much appreciated.

Comment: Didn't you get a compiler warning about "missing return" ?

Comment: You realize only in the first two cases are you ever actually returning anything from your function ? If your compiler isn't barking at you about "not all code paths return specified values" or words to that effect, you seriously need to turn up the warning level and treat them as errors (because that's exactly what they are).

Comment: Please show how you call the function when you see the problem

Comment: "and it does not work.." Please provide more details.. whar do you expect? What actually happens, etc...

Comment: As pointed by @WhozCraig , you do only set value for ifExist in one case, which means that if you call again the function in another case the value of ifExist stay the same. Add  *ifExist=false. At the beginning of the function.

Comment: No, ifExist should be set from false to true, never from true to false (hypothetically, it'd be possible the node is found, then further tree iteration hides this by clobbering ifExist back to false again). Plus, I think in only the base case should it be set at all so it's left unmodified if the node is not found, rather than explicitly set to false. Better yet, ifExists should not even be a bool, but instead just a pnr to node. Starting as NULL, addNewNode could point it to the existing node (if exists).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addNewNode, in your last two else if blocks, you're passing in &ifExist. But ifExist is a bool* already, should just pass in ifExist.

I'm not sure, but It's possible that the return statements only in the first if blocks is ok so long as those cover all possible base cases of your recursive function. [I was not thinking straight, the return statements are definitely necessary in all branches - I meant that setting ifExist to true is only required in the base cases...]

But yeah, the passing ifExist by reference (effectively now bool **) inside addNewNode is definitely not right.

EDIT: To clarify, in your outermost call to addNewNode where you have...

```
bool ifExist = false;
Tree->root = addNewNode(Tree->root, k, v, &ifExist);
```

...you do need to pass in by reference.
But inside addNewNode, your last two if else blocks should be

```
else if ((k == currentNode->key && v < currentNode->value) || k < currentNode->key)
{
    currentNode->left = addNewNode(currentNode->left, k, v, ifExist);
    currentNode->left->parent = currentNode;
}
else if ((k == currentNode->key && v > currentNode->value) || k > currentNode->key)
{
    currentNode->right = addNewNode(currentNode->right, k, v, ifExist);
    currentNode->right->parent = currentNode;
}
```

I would advise doing instead:

```
bool exists = false;
bool * ifExist = &exists;
Tree->root = addNewNode(Tree->root, k, v, ifExist);
```

That way, the way addNewNode arguments look is consistent everywhere... which will prevent future arcidents due to copy paste.